# Differential Equations: Find the first four terms in each of two solutions y1 and y2 ...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

The differential equation is

$y'' - xy' - y = 0$ with $x_0 = 1$

Now, I know how to find the recurrence relation... and it's given by:

$a_(n+2) = [(a_(n+1) + a_(n)) / (n+2)]$

But I can't quite figure out how to go about finding the first four terms of $y_1$ and $y_2...$  for instance, the answer for y1 given in the book is

$y_1 = 1 + (1/2)(x-1)^2 + (1/6)(x-1)^3 + (1/6)(x-1)^4$

But when I work it out myself I get

$y_1 = 1 + (1/2)(x-1)^2 + (1/6)(x-1)^3 + (1/8)(x-1)^4$

Comment: No. The first part of the problem states "Seek power series solutions of the given differential equation about the given point x0; find the recurrence relation."

Comment: You might to mention that you are after a Power Series solution about the point $x_0 = 1$ to be clear on the matter in your title / problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

The book's answer is correct. Also $y_2(x)=x-1+\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^3+\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^4+\cdots$ is the other solution.